# Using .Net Core Identity with Multiple .Net Core Web Applications through an API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've currently got two web projects within one solution (alongside various class libraries).

Web project 1 has Identity configured to log in through a web api:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        var res = await _authService.LoginAsync(loginModel.Username, loginModel.Password, loginModel.Persist);
        var data = new APIResult(res, _authService.CurrentErrors);
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

_authService.LoginAsync() just ends up using _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() to sign in using Identity.

Testing this with Swagger, the user is logged in and I can access it with IHttpContextAccessor and everything works perfectly fine.

Web project 2 is a .Net Core web application that simply serves Views, those views have javascript that calls the API from Web project 1. In the case of Login, thje below:

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function () {
    startLoginBtnLoading();
    var loginModel = {
        Username: $("#loginUsernameTxt").val(),
        Password: $("#loginPasswordTxt").val(),
        Persist: $("#loginPersistChk").is(":checked")
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@AuthUrl.LoginUrl',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(loginModel),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                toastr.success("Login was successful.", "Success");
                $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
                $.event.trigger({ type: "login", time: new Date() });
            }
            else {
                $.each(result.errors, function (ix, ob) {
                    toastr.error(ob, "Error");
                });
            }
            endLoginBtnLoading();
        }
    });
});
```

This successfully calls my API and allows the login (as I have set CORS to allow everything). However, the HttpContext doesn't stick between API calls, so when I next call my API and check HttpContext.User, I'm no longer authenticated.

I'm somewhat at a loss as to how I can login through the API and have the session persist the next time I call the API without moving it into the same project?

Comment: You should look at single sign on solution that would let you sign in with the same login to multiple applications. Identity Server 4 is what Microsoft recommends. Then you would have one authorization server application, and your two MVC applications being authentication through the same server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

You are calling login service from the client side.  The first login API will help user to login and it will generate HTTP Context in first application.

Please note that session state is a server side state storing mechanism.

After authentication that login API might be sending a cookie (which is not shown in your code).  This cookie or some kind of token inside that cookie is used to identify the server side session state corresponding to that user.

The cookie written by your login API will have some URLs mentioned with which this cookie can be sent.

Hence first thing, browser might not be sending that cookie to your second API.

Even you pass it explicitly, because session state is server side store and cookie is identifying session state from the server where login was performed.

One way to resolve this is - use OWIN/OIDC/OAuth and have your identity server perform your login operation.  If you use this, it would take care of generating and populating server side state for your API which needs login.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: You can [refer this blog](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) which says how can you use OWIN to create an authentication API.

Comment: I believe that there is a cookie stored from the API project and that it's probably not being sent with requests from the other site
Any suggestions on where to look for good information on implementing Oauth?

Comment: @AlexAshmore - that is what I am also suspecting.  You can verify this using Fiddler raw request.  One more thing - You can also check the path attribute for the cookie.  If path does not match the next URL then the cookie is not sent to the server.

Comment: I've installed fiddler and the Login response is setting a cookie, the cookie isnt being sent later on however.
I noticed the path you mentioned, and this is also in there: path=/; secure; samesite=lax; httponly
I'm not entirely sure how I'd get the cookies to be sent with future requests however!

Comment: @AlexAshmore: That's where I was suggesting to read about OIDC and OAUTH.  These protocols help you to allow this functionality - keeping login as a separate application and business functionality as a separate application.

Comment: @AlexAshmore added URL in my answer.  If you are using asp.net web api (not .net core) then you can use the contents from that blog for creating login APIs.